# PHP: Get data from JSON?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get a data from a JSON.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "object": "balance",
  "available": [
    {
      "currency": "aud",
      "amount": 0,
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "pending": [
    {
      "currency": "aud",
      "amount": 37706,
      "source_types": {
        "card": 37706
      }
    }
  ]
}{
  "object": "balance",
  "available": [
    {
      "currency": "aud",
      "amount": 0,
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "pending": [
    {
      "currency": "aud",
      "amount": 37706,
      "source_types": {
        "card": 37706
      }
    }
  ]
}{
  "object": "balance",
  "available": [
    {
      "currency": "aud",
      "amount": 0,
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "pending": [
    {
      "currency": "aud",
      "amount": 37706,
      "source_types": {
        "card": 37706
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All I need from there is the `available balance`.

I tried this code but the output of this code is just this `{{{`

This is my code:

```
$amount = $balanceArr['balance']['available'][0]['amount'];

echo $amount;
```

Note that the `$balanceArr` is just the JSON.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times.  Please refer to the link in the "Possible duplicate" comment.

Comment: actually, this has been answered for valid json. Yours is not.

Comment: Aside from this not being valid JSON (assuming you posted it exactly), there is no `'balance'` property. There is an `'object'` property with the value `'balance'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to json_decode the output, by default it will be objects, if you do

```
$balanceArr = json_decode($balanceArr, true);
```

above the code you posted, that will likely work

Your json is incorrectly formed also

```
$balanceArr[0]['available'][0]['amount']
```

Will work if your json string is valid (needs some commas and an array wrapping the whole thing)

Comment: I'd like to encourage you to _not_ answer questions like this, close as duplicate.  Be a good steward of SO.

Answer (score 1):

use json_decode to make php assoc array from json string http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php